# How to rank teams in google sheets based on two columns?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, vlookup, rank

[Image of the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le8Y8.jpg)

I have a spreadsheet with teams I want to rank. I have two columns - the first one is the main criteria teams should be ranked by, and the second one should be a tie-breaker when the first one is equal. If values in both columns are equal, teams should share the places. So, basically what I try to achieve is at least to rank teams based on two columns like in the "Kinda ok outcome" column. I've tried to do this using the built-in RANK function, but it only works with one column. In the best-case scenario, if it's even possible, I would like to format ranked places in a manner provided in the "Perfect outcome" column.

Comment: Please share your spreadsheet without personal info so that people can help you manage the data, your explanation was a little confusing, it would be nice to put in the spreadsheet that will share the expected final result.

That way it will be very clear what you want, I'll be waiting to help you.

Comment: Here is the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JUfUNduEr9ctQIeQuLnEdmKAUFm3M4VVCeSAdsZr-W0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="";;RANK(1*(B2:B&C2:C); 1*(B2:B&C2:C); 0)))
```

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="";;REGEXREPLACE(""&
 RANK(1*(B2:B&C2:C); 1*(B2:B&C2:C); 0)&"-"&VLOOKUP(
 RANK(1*(B2:B&C2:C); 1*(B2:B&C2:C); 0); SORT({
 RANK(1*(B2:B&C2:C); 1*(B2:B&C2:C); 0)\ IFERROR(
 RANK(1*(B2:B&C2:C); 1*(B2:B&C2:C); 0)+IFERROR(1/(1/(
 COUNTIFS(B2:B&C2:C; B2:B&C2:C; ROW(B2:B); "<="&ROW(B2:B))-1)); 
 "×"))}; 2; 0); 2; 0); "-$"; )))
```

[image]

---

for negative numbers:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B3:B8="",,RANK(1*((C3:C8&"0000")+D3:D8), 1*((C3:C8&"0000")+D3:D8), 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like it does what I want but it works kinda weird - in outputs REF errors first, and the correct result below them.

Comment: Never mind, it works as intended. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, now it solves even my best-case scenario! Thank you very much!

Comment: The first formula works for my problem, but it breaks if the number in column C is negative. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: @TimB can you share a copy of your sheet with sample?

Comment: @player0 here's the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tg-0Z2pdzOaV-5p46NiWug7RhgPMS3El1dntE63t1UM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @TimB see your sheet

Comment: @player0  I don't understand what's going on inside the RANK function but it works, thank you

Comment: @TimB before we joined C3 value with D3 value to produce combined number, but now with negative numbers around we add 5 zeros to the end of C3 value and sum it with D3 value all because that minus sign that will render the number to be a text string instead of numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

For this work, I recommend using a simpler mode, which would be the function `SORT`:

```
=SORT(A2:E15,2,FALSE,3,FALSE)
```

Your region seems to use `;` instead of `,` so in your specific case it would look like this:

```
=SORT(A2:E15;2;FALSE;3;FALSE)
```

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: In my case, the columns with teams and criteriaes must stay untouched, that's why I was trying to do in with RANK. But I just can't make it work with two columns.

Comment: Could you put in the spreadsheet what is the expected result for me to understand better? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've modified the spreadsheet to make my point more clear.

Comment: I'm sorry but unfortunately I couldn't understand what your expected result is, if by chance nobody shows up and can help you, please put a separate table with the data in the original sequence and another table with the data in the sequence expected by you. So I can visualize it easily.